# Declare a required array parameter using Rails Strong Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-6

In my Rails controller I'd like to *require* a single parameter, `emails`. It must be an array.

This is allowed.

```
emails[]=foo@bar.com&emails[]=up@down.com
```

This is not allowed.

```
emails=foo@bar.com
```

`params.require(:emails)` will allow both. The former comes as an Array. The latter as a String. This is a problem.

`params.permit(emails: [])` does not require an `emails` parameter.

`params.require(:emails).permit([])` does not work because `params.require(:emails)` gets clever and returns an Array, not an ActionController::Parameters.

How do I allow `emails[]=...` and disallow `emails=...`?

Comment: Strong Parameters is mostly concerned with screening, it's not necessarily there to do validation. You could always kick back an error if your strong params are missing `emails` in the correct form, and even do that as a `before_action` handler.

Comment: @tadman I have worked around it manually. I ask because it seems an odd oversight that `params.require(...).permit(...)` works fine with hashes but not arrays; I assume I'm missing something. I can't find where `params.require(:thing) -> ActionController::Parameters` vs `params.require(:things) -> Array` is documented.

Answer (score 0):

Like what tadman said, Screening is what Strong Parameters does mostly.

You can look into Grape, perhaps it can show you some directions for your concerns

```
  desc "API demo", {}
  params do
    requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'ID'
    requires :name, type: Boolean, desc: 'xxx'
  end
```

Error msg would be received if you pass it an unexpected type of parameters